# issues connecting testflight to a device

Tags: ios, testflight

I'm trying to test an app via testflight. I've done it before and it's always worked fine. Now for the first time my tester is running into a problem trying to connect her iOS device to her testflight account.

So basically when she presses "install" the TestflightAccess profile she is taken to the "Settings" app, which is just normal. But the popupwindow that prompts her to actually install the profile doesn't ever show up. What can she do to install testflight anyways? What could be the problem? Is there any workaround?

the "profile" option doesn't even appear in the settings app. here's a photo[image]

Comment: Did you try to remove the TestFlight Profile from: Settings/General/Profiles and restart the phone?

Comment: the problem is that the Profiles part doesn't even appear on her iPad

Comment: Which iPad / iOS is she using?

Comment: she's on iPad Air and OS 7.1.2

Comment: and that the "profiles" isn't there should mean she doesn't have any installed